# ajax is not a function inside a namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, namespaces, javascript-namespaces

I am trying to create a namespace that contains all the calls of my application, but I do not know why when I try to do an Ajax call inside the namespace it says that ajax is not a function

I Tried to set jQuery as a dependency and pass it to the namespace but still having the issue

Here is the js

```
   var FOF = FOF || {};
   FOF.Users = {
    init: function(userRequest){

    var request = userRequest.request || '';
    var callbacks = userRequest.callbacks || {};
    var userId = userRequest.userId || 0;
    var event = userRequest.domainEvent || false;
    var dependency = userRequest.dependency ||  false;
    console.log(userRequest.dependency);
    console.log(userRequest);


    switch(request) {
        case 'getUser':{
            FOF.Users.getUserData(callbacks,dependency);
            break;
        }
        default:{
            console.log('Param Request Empty or not valid');
        }
    }


    },
    getUserData : function(callbacks,dependency){

        dependency.ajax({
            url: "Mocks/users.json",
            data: {},
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'get',
            success: function (data) {
                if (!isObjectEmpty(callbacks)) {
                    callbacks.run(data);
                }
                if(event){
                    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(event, {detail: {data}}));
                }

            },
            error : function (data) {
                if (!isObjectEmpty(callbacks)) {
                    callbacks.errors(data);
                }
                if(event){
                    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(event, {detail: {data}}));
                }
            },
            cache: false,
        });


        /*
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', encodeURI('Mocks/users.json'));
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                console.log('Request Done', xhr);

            }
            else {
                console.log('Request Failed');
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
        */

    }

}




$(document).ready(function($){

    var userRequest = {
        dependency : jQuery,
        request: 'getUser',
        userId : 1,
        callbacks :getUserCallbacks,
        domainEvent: 'getUser' 
    }

    var getUserCallbacks = {
        run: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        errors: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        serverError : function(data){
            console.log('La Culpa es de Api, preguntar a Pedro');
        },
    }

    FOF.Users.init(userRequest);
});




function isObjectEmpty(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
}
```

And also a Plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/1fPelOGyMiroOWWXMXXU?p=preview

I hope that my englis is good enough, If you have any questions please ask me
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
var dependency = FOF.Users.jQuery ||  false;
```

`PDF.Users.jQuery` is not actually jQuery (it appears to be undefined).

Did you perhaps mean to say:

```
var dependency = usersRequest.dependency || false
```

**EDIT**

I'll bet your AJAX request goes through, but your callbacks aren't getting called, because of [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) and the fact that you've declared `userRequest` before `getUserCallbacks`.

Declare `getUserCallbacks` *before* `userRequest` - otherwise, `userRequest.callbacks` will be `undefined`.

```
var getUserCallbacks = {
    run: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    errors: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    serverError : function(data){
        console.log('La Culpa es de Api, preguntar a Pedro');
    },
};

var userRequest = {
    dependency : jQuery,
    request: 'getUser',
    userId : 1,
    callbacks :getUserCallbacks,
    domainEvent: 'getUser' 
}
```

**EDIT #2**

In addition to my previous edit, you're including jQuery slim in your header. jQuery slim does not include the `ajax` functionality of jQuery. If you want to use ajax, just include jQuery and not jQuery slim.

Comment: Opps, yeah i changed it trying to test a solution and forgot about it, i have updated the code, but still not working

Comment: Same error `Uncaught TypeError: dependency.ajax is not a function` It cant find jquery even if i pass it as dependency

Comment: @Vistor - see both my edits to the answer, they will solve your problem.

Comment: I see, damn bootstrap. Now its working fine, thanks!